# Can you get your bullets back from Nikki in Metro 2033 after she tricks you?

Tags: metro-2033

In my first play through of Metro 2033 (Redux), in the 2nd chapter, I encountered Nikki. She appeared to be a prostitute, so like any good gamer, I tried to have my character "get lucky." Well, it back fired. Nikki tricked me, and some other character ended up robbing me of all my bullets (currency). Is there any way to get these back after the event occurs, besides reloading the save?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You can't get your bullets back from Nikki in Metro 2033 after she tricks you.

Comment: You can however reload a previous save to avoid loosing the bullets, but it's kind of cheaty.